# Why isn't Xcode recording these user interface tests?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testing

Xcode has the ability to live record UI tests, as demonstrated by [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BETaeOr7jnQ) - the user clicks buttons on the Simulator and the code appears in test.

However, when I do the same action on [this freshly pushed to GitHub Xcode project](https://github.com/joereddington/MrsLandingham/tree/master) nothing code appears. What is my missing ingredient?

This is the screen I see. 
[image]

and [this is a recording of what it looks like live](https://youtu.be/USu1yh3SHYE).  What am I missing?

EDIT - tried an entirely new user account, different project, button didn't appear at all.  [Twich video here](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/282937370?t=00h46m39s), I must be missing something...

Comment: your github link is broken

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.